# RouteValueDictionary in querystring with t4mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, t4mvc

Whenever I use t4Mvc to create a form post Url, e.g.

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm(MVC.Admin.Login.Index())) { %>
```

It generates a route like the following:

```
<form method="post" action="/admin/login/index?RouteValueDictionary=System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary">
```

or when i use

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm(MVC.Admin.Login.Index(null))) { %>
```

where the method is expecting an action parameter it generates

```
<form method="post" action="/admin/login?TempData=System.Web.Mvc.TempDataDictionary&amp;ViewData=System.Web.Mvc.ViewDataDictionary&amp;ViewEngineCollection=System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngineCollection">
```

Anyone else had this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see, this happens because the T4MVC overload needs the form method to be explicitly passed in.  e.g. try

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm(MVC.Admin.Login.Index(), FormMethod.Post)) { %>
```